# Stop signal send trigger for specific Sender

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

I'm using **Django 2.2**

In my application, there is a shared user feature and every shared user are added to **User** model with `is_shared` field set to **True**.

The shared user is linked to a user in **SharedUser** model like

```
class SharedUser(models.Model)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCASE, related_name='owner_user')
    shared_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCASE, related_name='shared_user')
```

On delete of a record from **SharedUser** model, I also have to delete the linked `shared_user` record from the **User** model. For that I'm using the `post_signal` receiver.

**receivers.py**

```
@receiver(post_delete, sender=SharedUser, dispatch_uid='post_delete_shared_user')
def post_delete_shared_user(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        if instance and instance.shared_user:
            owner = instance.user
            instance.shared_user.delete()
    except:
        pass
```

and the receiver is loaded in the **app.py** config

```
class SharedUsersConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'shared_users'

    def ready(self):
        from . import receivers
```

Now, whenever a record from the **SharedUser** model is deleted, it makes a lot of SQL queries.

[image]

When the `import receivers` is removed from the **apps.py** file.

[image]

There are a lot more SQL queries being made when the receiver is used to delete the associated user.

In my use case, there is nowhere the `shared_user` is associated to any other model other than **SharedUser** model.

1. **How can I reduce the query on deleting a user?**
2. **Can I disable sending the signal when the user is deleted for this scenario only? Since a `shared_user` is not related to any other model.**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `shared_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCASE, related_name='shared_user')` specifically the `on_delete` attribute.

Every time you remove a `User` record, all related `SharedUser` records gets also removed.

To prevent deletion you should use `on_delete=models.SET_NULL`.

Comment: I believe `on_delete` works on associated **User** model. Means, when the user is deleted from **User** model, it will cascade the linked `shared_user`. But it doesn't work the reverse way. If it does, then disabling signal receiver won't make only 6 SQL queries.

Comment: I think that the problem there is a strange loop. Every time you remove a `SharedUser`, in a signal you remove `User` wich in cascade also remove `SharedUser` that trigger the delete signal that again remove a `User` and... loop. You have to keep in mind that a sql.DELETE is not necesary commited on model.delete() and until your record gets really deleted you will walk througt the loop. Maybe you are looking for handle commited data (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/transactions/#performing-actions-after-commit)